# Why I am receiving an error message about cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When i run the program I am receiving this error message: require_relative 'models/pets.rb'

appication_controller.rb

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require_relative 'models/pets.rb'

 class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base

  get '/' do
    #home
    erb :index
  end
  get '/questions' do
    erb :questions
  end
post '/results' do 
  @dog=get_results(params)

  erb :results
end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: May be silly to ask, but do you have under the folder `models` the file called `pets.rb` (spelled exactly this way and not, let's say `pet.rb`) ?

Comment: @Jeff K here the complete error LoadError in StaticPagesController#index
cannot load such file -- /vagrant/****/app/controllers/models/pets.rb

Comment: @AmitA under my models folder the name of my file is pet.rb not pets.rb

Comment: @user2803053 Then change the line `require_relative 'models/pets.rb'` to `require_relative 'models/pet'` and your problem will be solved. Note that you can omit the `.rb` ending when using `require` or `require_relative` - it's optional. You only need the `.rb` ending when you're using `load`.

Comment: @AmitA I change the line to require_relative 'models/pet' but I am still receiving the same error: require_relative 'models/pet'

Comment: @user2803053 do you get the error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- /path/to/file` or something else? Can you copy-paste the exact error message?

Comment: @AmitaA error: cannot load such file -- /vagrant/*****/app/controllers/models/pet

Comment: @user2803053 ok, change it to `require_relative '../models/pet'`. I assume your `models` folder is not inside the `controllers` folder, but rather under the `app` folder. `require_relative` means - relative to the folder of the current file. Based on your error message, your current file appears to be in the `controllers` folder.

Comment: @AmitA When i change the line I get a new error: undefined method `action' for StaticPagesController:Class and    controller.action(action).call(env)

Comment: @user2803053 Congrats. you solved your require problem. What you pasted now is a totally different problem. Look at the backtrace to understand where it is coming from. I suspect that your `StaticPagesController` is not properly inheriting from `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without the exact error message. It seems like you might not have a file under models/pets.rb

Can you post the output of the `tree` command in the current directory and paste the exact error?

Comment: error: cannot load such file -- /vagrant/*****/app/controllers/models/pet